# Completed a row before a selectall

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array with my column title and i want my first cell to have "A1" as title.
I tried like that :

```
var title=mtable.append("thead").append("tr");
title.append("td").text("A1");
title.selectAll("td")
        .data(lTitre)
        .enter().append("td")
        .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
```

My code doesn't draw the first column title: 2007 (as show under). how can i solve this ?

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
 !!!! <td>2007</td> !!!!! is missing here 
    <td>2008</td>
    <td>2009</td>
    <td>2010</td>
    <td>2011</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, if you check the `__data__` bound to `<td>A1</td>`, you'll see it has `__data__.key == 2007`. This happens because whenever your `selectAll()` statement matches any elements in your current selection, the `.data()` function binds data to existing elements before it creates the entering selection. To fix this, simply use a `selectAll()` function that doesn't match any existing elements:

```
var title = mtable.append("thead").append("tr");
title.append("td").text("A1");
title.selectAll(".new")
        .data(lTitre)
        .enter().append("td")
        .text(function(d) { return d.key; });
```

Comment: @user1443858 you should accept the answer(and upvote) the answer if it has worked to solve your problem